# File transfer in erlang

Tags: ssh, erlang, file-transfer

I am a newbie to erlang and would like to know how to get ssh connection to a remote machine A and transfer files using ssh .Any help would be really appreciated.I have allready searched in other forums regarding the same but could not understand the code

Answer (score 2):

```
1> ssh:start().
ok
2> {ok, Pid, ConnRef} = ssh_sftp:start_channel("my.server.com").
{ok,<0.52.0>,<0.47.0>}
3> ssh_sftp:list_dir(Pid, ".").
{ok,[".login",".bash_history",".login_conf",".profile",".rhosts",".lesshst",".ssh","some","other","files",".shrc","..","."]}
4> {ok, Data} = ssh_sftp:read_file(Pid, ".login").
{ok,<<"# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/share/skel/dot.login 190477 2009-03-27 21:13:14Z ru $\n#\n# .login - csh login scri"...>>}
```

Comment: Hi I tried the above steps however it fails during ssh:start() with the below error{error,{not_started,crypto}}.Is there any sort of dependencies that i require

Comment: All right i got it I did crypto:start() .  Before ssh:start()

Comment: {ok, Pid, ConnRef} = ssh_sftp:start_channel("XX.XX.XX.XX") .
 New host 192.168.1.55 accept [y/n]?                                                                                                              it asks for entering 'y' or 'n' however the terminal freezes and Erlang is not taking my input not sure how to proceed

Comment: Erlang uses standard OpenSSH files. This error means the remote host is not in your known_hosts file on your account. The easiest way is to connect to the remote host first using standard SSH before doing that in Erlang. The standard SSH will update the file appropriately. Alternatively you would need to update the known_hosts yourself.

Comment: it  says the same thing even if do for known host or even after taking ssh is ther no way to enter 'y' or 'n' through terminal

Comment: According to the documentation http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#connect-3 you should be able to use this option `{silently_accept_hosts, boolean()}` to accept the host.